# Web script to click some buttons and save some html pages

Tags: language-agnostic

I am trying to go through a site with a bunch of links. I click on a link, save the page, click on a button, save a page. Then go back and repeat it for a huge number of links. I want to write a script to do that for me. I know C++ but I want to do Javascript for this, what is a good place to get me started? What would be a good IDE to use?

Comment: So you want something that will save a whole web page by clicking on a link for it?

Comment: Have you looked at wget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[firebug](http://getfirebug.com)!  it's a firefox add-on, and allows you to set breakpoints and debug, as well as to explore the page in terms of css, html, javascript, and such.

it's a powerful, wondeful tool.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a crawler or spider (like what a search engine does to look for content). There are lots of tools you can use for that. Someone mentioned [`wget`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), which has options for recursively downloading / crawling pages.

If you want to do it within the browser you could try [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) or [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/quickstart.html).

If you want to use a scripting language to follow links, fill forms, click buttons, and save pages you could use these kinds of libraries:

- Python: [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/)
- Perl: [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is the right choice!

GreaseMonkey!

.. or you can try witr or AutoIt.

Let us know how this goes :-)

Comment: Thanks, I am reading http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page to learn how to write my script. Any other resources you would recommend for Javascript programming?

Comment: You can locate tons of tutorials through GOOGLE :-)